# How to use jQuery replaceWith conditionally and properly?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML with this line:

```
<FONT size=4>Hello</FONT>
<FONT size=5>Hello</FONT>
```

And I want to use jQuery to replace the font with this:

If font size = 4 replace with `<h2 class="h2class">Hello</h2>`
If font size = 5 replace with `<h3 class="h3class">Hello</h3>`

I've been trying to use the replaceWith() function like that:

```
$('font').replaceWith('<h2 class="h2class"></h2>');
```

But then I lose the text and I can't quite work out how to check the font size either.

So, two questions:
1. How can I do this conditionally based on the font size
2. How can I do this without loosing the original text.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('font[size="4"]').replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<h2 />', {"class": "h2class"}).append($(this).contents())
});
$('font[size="5"]').replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<h3 />', {"class": "h3class"}).append($(this).contents())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
$('font').wrapInner('<h2 class="h2class" />').children().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('font').replaceWith(function(i, content) {
    var tag = +$(this).attr('size')===5 ? 'h2' : 'h3';
    return $('<'+tag+'/>', {
        'class': tag+'class',
        text: content
    });
});
```